# How to send AWS SES email with pdf link stored on S3 (not publicly accessible)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I want to design a solution to send weekly reports to users. These reports will be in PDF stored on S3 once generated via some task. I want to use AWS SES to send email to our users with the links of these PDF reports stored on S3 but it should have access restrictions. Reports on S3 can only be viewed if the user click on the link provided by Email. One more issue is that the reports can go out to multiple emails for an account which are not registered user emails in our system but have been asked by client to include in the report email.

Is there a way to achieve this? As per my knowledge, files on S3 can be public(accessible to anyone) or can be accessed via IAM. I can not make the PDF on S3 public due to privacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use presigned URLs to achieve what you want. These are temporary URLs that can be used to download/upload to s3. The link will expire in the time you specify when generating them (default 1 hour).

Read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: There are some expiration restrictions using this method as mentioned in url https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/  What if I want to have an expiration date of more than 7 days?

Comment: @IdrisRampurawala Beyond 7 days, you would need to create your own authentication mechanism to grant access. Or, you could rely on obfuscated filenames (a bit like Dropbox uses).

Comment: I researched a bit and found out that we can make s3 accessible privately via CloudFront signed urls. We can set custom expiration on these urls. Still looking for an example of the same.

Comment: Created a blog for both of the above use cases. Maybe others will find it useful. [Blog Link](https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/share-your-aws-s3-private-content-with-others-without-making-it-public-4k59)